# MPI_Sendrecv deadlocks on 3+ processes

Tags: c, mpi, parallel-processing

Trying to do a "halo/ghost" row exchange and I'm stumped by a deadlock (in code snippet below the picture).
The "halo" rows to be exchanged are represented as dark-grey lines (in the picture) and as `hp[0]` and `hp[M-1]` (in the code).

[Can't post pictures; not enough reputation. Again in words: `hp[0]` and `hp[M-1]` are "halo" rows (i.e. rows to be exchanged) while `hp[1]` and `hp[M-2]` (and all rows in-between) are to be calculated with.]

**Why would this snippet (which works OK for 2 processes) deadlock with 3+ processes?**

```
// in-between processes ("P1" and "P2" in the picture; 
// one of "P1" and "P2" is of course missing in the case of 3 processes)
if (p > 0 && p < P-1) 
{ 
    MPI_Sendrecv(hp[M-2], N, MPI_DOUBLE, p+1, 0, 
                 hp[0],   N, MPI_DOUBLE, p-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s);  
    MPI_Sendrecv(hp[1],   N, MPI_DOUBLE, p-1, 1, 
                 hp[M-1], N, MPI_DOUBLE, p+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s);  
}
// root process ("P0" in the picture)
else if (p == 0) 
{
    MPI_Sendrecv(hp[M-2], N, MPI_DOUBLE, p+1, 0, 
                 hp[M-1], N, MPI_DOUBLE, p+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s);  
}
// last process ("P3" in the picture)
else 
{
    MPI_Sendrecv(hp[1],   N, MPI_DOUBLE, p-1, 1, 
                 hp[0],   N, MPI_DOUBLE, p-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s); 
}
```

Platform: Windows XP with [DeinoMPI](http://mpi.deino.net/) GUI which has a button `"Show Messages"` which `"Interrupts the running job and prints the current state of the message queues"`

Well, this is an example of a "current state" (when in deadlock):

```
Rank 0 queues:
 Posted receive queue:
  rank=2, tag=1, context_id=1(Collective), count=0, dtype=MPI_BYTE
Rank 1 queues:
 Posted receive queue:
  rank=0, tag=0, context_id=MPI_COMM_WORLD, count=10, dtype=MPI_DOUBLE
 Received but unmatched queue:
  rank=2, tag=2, context_id=MPI_COMM_WORLD, length=80
  rank=2, tag=2, context_id=MPI_COMM_WORLD, length=80
  rank=0, tag=1, context_id=1(Collective), length=0
Rank 2 queues:
 Posted receive queue:
  rank=1, tag=1, context_id=MPI_COMM_WORLD, count=10, dtype=MPI_DOUBLE
```

Why is there an `MPI_BYTE` as datatype and `1(Collective)` as context? And why has `Rank 0` in his receive queue a `rank = 2`?!

PS: Forgive me if I'm asking (and missing) something obvious, but I've read too many SO questions already, alas with no solution to be found. So many, that I know the HPC trio of Jonathan Dursi, High Performance Mark, and suszterpatt.

### Update (full loop)

There isn't much more to the loop, so I can post it in its entirety: it has some commented [MPI_Barrier](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Barrier.html)s because I was randomly trying which combination would work (talk about a "black box").  So, besides those `MPI_Barrier`s (and a `MPI_Sccaterv` before the loop) there isn't any other communication going on. For the purpose of testing, I do a `return 0;` before `MPI_Gatherv` after the loop (so this should have no deadlock implications as well).

```
while (1)
{
    difference = 0.0;

    //MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // in-between processes ("P1" and "P2" in the picture; 
    // one of "P1" and "P2" is of course missing in the case of 3 processes)
    if (p > 0 && p < P-1) 
    { 
        MPI_Sendrecv(hp[M-2], N, MPI_DOUBLE, p+1, 0, 
                     hp[0],   N, MPI_DOUBLE, p-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s);  
        MPI_Sendrecv(hp[1],   N, MPI_DOUBLE, p-1, 1, 
                     hp[M-1], N, MPI_DOUBLE, p+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s);  
    }
    // root process ("P0" in the picture)
    else if (p == 0) 
    {
        MPI_Sendrecv(hp[M-2], N, MPI_DOUBLE, p+1, 0, 
                     hp[M-1], N, MPI_DOUBLE, p+1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s);  
    }
    // last process ("P3" in the picture)
    else 
    {
        MPI_Sendrecv(hp[1],   N, MPI_DOUBLE, p-1, 1, 
                     hp[0],   N, MPI_DOUBLE, p-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s); 
    }
    //MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // calculate "hpNEW" for each inner point
    for (y = 1; y < M-1; ++y)
        for (x = 1; x < N-1; ++x)
        {
            hpNEW[y][x] = (hp[y][x-1] + hp[y][x+1] + hp[y-1][x] + hp[y+1][x]) / 4.0;
            if (fabs( hpNEW[y][x] - hp[y][x] ) > diff)
                difference = fabs(hpNEW[y][x] - hp[y][x]);
        }

    if (difference < EPSILON)
        break;

    // transfer "hpNEW"'s calculated inner points to "hp" for next iteration 
    for (y = 1; y < M-1; ++y)
        for (x = 1; x < N-1; ++x)
            hp[y][x] = hpNEW[y][x];
} // while END
```

**One process will indeed `break` out of the loop first ... would/could this cause a deadlock (among other possible things unbeknownst to me)?** If so, how to prevent it?

One other thing regarding "weird" `tag`s. I just ran the above loop with all `MPI_Barrier`s commented out ... and got this "strange" (there is a `tag=4`!) message queue state:

```
Rank 0 queues:
 Posted receive queue:
  rank=1, tag=4, context_id=1(Collective), count=30, dtype=MPI_DOUBLE
 Received but unmatched queue:
  rank=2, tag=1, context_id=1(Collective), length=0
Rank 1 queues:
 Posted receive queue:
  rank=0, tag=0, context_id=MPI_COMM_WORLD, count=10, dtype=MPI_DOUBLE
 Received but unmatched queue:
  rank=2, tag=1, context_id=MPI_COMM_WORLD, length=80
Rank 2 queues:
 Posted receive queue:
  rank=1, tag=1, context_id=1(Collective), count=0, dtype=MPI_BYTE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are others, we're just the ones that have been active recently...

That's interesting about DeinoMPI on windows, I didn't realize it had nice tools to see what's going on in real time like that.

So you definitely aren't asking something obvious; on the face of it, I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted.  I personally find it clearer to use something like `MPI_PROC_NULL` to simplify the code logic:

```
left = p-1;
if (left < 0) left = MPI_PROC_NULL;
right = p+1;
if (right >= P) right = MPI_PROC_NULL;

MPI_Sendrecv(hp[M-2], N, MPI_DOUBLE, right, 0, 
             hp[0],   N, MPI_DOUBLE, left , 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s);  
MPI_Sendrecv(hp[1],   N, MPI_DOUBLE, left , 1, 
             hp[M-1], N, MPI_DOUBLE, right, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s);
```

and let the MPI library deal with the edge cases, rather than having the explicit tests `if (p == 0)`, etc; but that's a question of taste and what you're going to do with the code afterwards.

The situation in the message queues is confusing enough that I don't think the code you've posted is responsible for the deadlock, although it might be where (say) rank 1 ends up manifesting the deadlock -- it might be where rank 1 is seen to hang.

If you look at what's going on, rank 1 is waiting for 10 doubles from rank 0, and rank 2 is waiting for 10 doubles from rank 1, so it's like the rightward-sending phase of your halo filling --  1 and 2 have posted their respective receives for that phase -- except 2's tag is wrong, it's receiving 10 doubles with tag 1, which shouldn't happen (by the code above).

On top of that, rank 0 is waiting for that collective to finish (with zero data associated with it -- a barrier, maybe?  Or an MPI_Finalize or something else with implied synchronization?) and so isn't sending to 1; rank 1 already has a message as part of that collective, so if it gets finished it would clear that immediately and do it's part of that collective.   It also has two messages already sitting there from rank 2, with tag 2?  So that must come from another phase of communication outside the current code snippet.

Just guessing from what I see in the queue, I'm guessing the code goes something like:

```
loop { 
    communication as posted above;

    another phase of communication;

    synchronization (barrier?)
}
```

and it's that second phase of communication which has a subtle error.

**Update**:

Ok, so processes exiting the loop at different times will definately cause lockups as processes start waiting for messages which will never come from their neighbours.  But this is easy to fix; after you locally calculate the biggest difference, you then find the maximum of that difference across processors with an [`MPI_Allreduce`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Allreduce.html); only if the global difference between hp and hpNEW is everywhere less than EPSILON do you continue.

```
// calculate "hpNEW" for each inner point locally
for (y = 1; y < M-1; ++y)
    for (x = 1; x < N-1; ++x)
    {
        hpNEW[y][x] = (hp[y][x-1] + hp[y][x+1] + hp[y-1][x] + hp[y+1][x]) / 4.0;
        if (fabs( hpNEW[y][x] - hp[y][x] ) > diff)
            diff = fabs(hpNEW[y][x] - hp[y][x]);
    }

// find the maximum of all the local differences

MPI_Allreduce (&diff, &globaldiff, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (globaldiff < EPSILON)
    break;
```

Comment: Jonathan, thank you for the reply. The wrong tags are strange indeed (especially the `tag=2`) since there is no other phase of communication (apart from `MPI_Barrier`s; see the **updated question** with the complete loop). [Sadly, lacking "15 reputation" I can't vote you up.]

Comment: Ah, ok, I still don't know what's going on with the tag=2, but yes, if you can have one process breaking out of the loop before the others, you'll certainly get deadlock, as at least one of the "in the loop" processes will be stuck forever waiting for a receive from the "out of the loop" process which will never come.

Comment: How would you prevent this from happening (one process breaking and leaving everyone else in deadlock)? Or is this a design flaw and I should somehow (how?) rearrange the code? I am _really_ stuck on this one.

Comment: Take a look at the code above under update to the answer; you want the processes to leave only if *everyone's* difference is less than epsilon, otherwise you have to keep iterating.

Comment: Beautiful ... such a neat and natural use of `MPI_Allreduce`! Thank you Jonathan! 

Now I'll also try to find how to `MPI_Scatterv` chunks of **2D** (now only **1D**) array from your other answers ... and so avoid clumsy (and expensive) decomposing **2D** to **1D** and then back to **2D** `hp[][]` in the code above. Should I not "get it", expect to be bothered again. :)